# A geometric sequence has first term $256$ and ratio $0.75$. Find the smallest $n$ for which the sum of the first $n$ terms exceeds $1000$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A geometric sequence whose first term = 256 and whose common ratio is 0.75. Find the smallest number of n for which the sum of the first n terms of the sequence exceeds 1000.

My turn:
$$S_n = \frac{256(1-(0.75)^n)}{1-0.75} > 1000$$
$$n \log{0.75} < \log{\frac{3}{128}}$$
$$n < 13.04 $$ then
$$n = 13$$

> What is wrong with my solution because 13 does not satisfy the requires but 14 does ?

Comment: $\log(0.75)$ is negative.  You forgot to swap the direction of the inequality sign.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: For $a,b>0$, if $c>0$ then
$$ac < b c \implies a < b.$$
What happens if $c <0$?